# Angular 2 slider range - Add Ion.RangeSlider library

Tags: jquery, angular, webpack, slider, angular-cli

I have seen this library that have a slider range feature but in AngularJS:
[Ion.RangeSlider](https://github.com/IonDen/ion.rangeSlider)

And there is a guy make a wrapper for it to work in Angular 2:
[ng2-ion-range-slider](https://github.com/PhilippStein/ng2-ion-range-slider)

I am using `webpack` not `Angular-CLI`.

I have tried to follow his install instructions and it is worked but with no styles.

Can anyone help me to find out where to put the style paths in the webpack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have made it after some failed attempts.

First, I am using `Angular 5` with `Webpack` and `Angular Material`.

1. add the slider library and its wrapper to `package.json` file.

   "ion-rangeslider": "2.2.0"
   "ng2-ion-range-slider": "~1.0.3"
2. I have added the slider styles to `theme.scss` file inside my project, like this:

   @import '~@angular/material/_theming.scss';
   @import '~ion-rangeslider/css/ion.rangeSlider.css';
   @import '~ion-rangeslider/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinModern.css';
   // @import '~ion-rangeslider/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinFlat.css';

> add the style you need depends on the skin you choose.

3. There is no need to import `javascript` file in `webpack`, I mean these two files:

   jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
   ion-rangeslider/js/ion.rangeSlider.js
4. Import `IonRangeSliderModule` in your `AppModule`.

   import { IonRangeSliderModule } from 'ng2-ion-range-slider';

Now, you can use it like:

```
<ion-range-slider type="double" [min]="min" [max]="max" [step]="step" [from]="value1" 
                  [to]="value2" (onFinish)="sliderChange($event)">
</ion-range-slider>
```

---

***Update***

For those don't use Angular Material

You can import `css` and `scss` file inside the `webpack` configuration file.

1-) Install `sass-loader` library:

```
"sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
"sass-resources-loader": "^1.3.3",
```

2-) Create new `scss` file inside the project with any name (Ex. `./src/index.scss`) and add all the `css` and `scss` you want to import to this file.

3-) Inside `webpack.common.js` file, add this to rules or change it if exist:

```
/**
 * To string and sass loader support for *.scss files (from Angular components)
 * Returns compiled CSS content as a string
 *
 */
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader',
    {
      loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
      options: {
        // Provide path to the file with resources
        resources: `./src/index.scss`
      },
    },
  ],
  exclude: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
},
```

Comment: Perfect! This is absolutely what I needed. I struggled with different slider implementations. This is the only one that integrated well w/Angular 5 thanks to your post! :-)

Comment: I am having a similar issue but this solution doesn't work for me, am not using angular-material. I don't have theme.scss in my project. Where should I import those slider styles?

Comment: @NgugiNdung'u ,I have udpated the answer, check it again, hope it help you.

Comment: @EbraheemAlrabee', this one doesn't work either. I have my .scss file which I import `@import '~ion-rangeslider/css/ion.rangeSlider.css';`and 
`@import '~ion-rangeslider/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinModern.css';`. I wonder if file path is correct since no styles are loaded. 

Shouldn't we point to node_modules folder where the styles are? I have tried to point to node modules folder with no results.

Comment: @MichaelNiño please share with me your implementation. I am stuck with these imports of .js and .css fies

Comment: @NgugiNdung'u , The first answer is my implantation and the update worked for me too, can you tell what library are you using exactly, or you can show me the error, maybe you can create a question and I well go there, for the best.

Comment: @NgugiNdung'u

I am not using SCSS. My style.css is below:


`@import '~ion-rangeslider/css/ion.rangeSlider.css';`

`@import '~ion-rangeslider/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinHTML5.css';`

Comment: @Nitesh, I have not trying it yet.

Comment: How to update the slider or reset slider using angular5

Comment: @Jigs1212, you can update or reset the slider by changing the values `from` and `to` inside the ts file.